# Taking string input using pointers in c gives me segmentation fault in one function. Same block of code works fine for another function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

So I want to take inputs of names as strings using char* pointers.
I looked online and found a solution by giving my pointer memory using malloc and then taking the input using `scanf`, as shown below:

```
  char *userInput = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  printf("\nEnter a name: ");
  scanf("%s",userInput);
  char *name = (char*)malloc(getLength(userInput)* sizeof(char));
  name = userInput;
  if(name == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }
  free(userInput);
```

This works, so I copied and pasted it to another function where similar input is required as below:

```
  char *userInput = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  printf("\nEnter a name: ");
  scanf("%s",userInput);
  char *searched = (char*)malloc(getLength(searched)* sizeof(char));
  searched = userInput;
  if(searched == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }
  free(userInput);
```

But when I run the code for this function, it gives me "exited, segmentation fault".

Any ideas on why it doesn't work in my second function?

EDIT: getLength() is a function that returns the length of a given string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You have a memory leak in `name = userInput;`. You allocated memory for `name`, but overwrite the pointer that pointed to it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to allocate memory twice? Once you allocate memory for `userInput`, you can just use that memory.

Comment: What is `getLength()` and how does it differ from `strlen()`?

Comment: `getLength(searched)` tries to find the length of an uninitialized variable -- the variable `seached` is initialized indirectly with that length only after that call. That's also the difference between the two code snippets: The original uses `getLength(userInput)`. (But take into account what Barmar has said: Don't allocate and then immediately overwrite the handle to the allocated memory.)

Comment: (There's also the issue that you say `name = userInput` and later `free(userInput)`, which will also make the memory pointed to by `name` invalid.)

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *userInput = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and expression just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2)  The returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that case.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  If not successful, call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",userInput);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful Note: those functions return the number successful 'input format conversion' specifiers. 2) when using the specifier `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `name = userInput;`  that is NOT how to copy a string,  Infact, all is does is overlay the pointer that was in `name`, so the original pointer is lost.  This results in a memory leak.  Suggest using `strcpy()` to copy the string.  Note: be sure that the function: `getLength()` allows an extra character for the NUL terminating byte of the string

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Memory not allocated");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr` and when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror("Memory not allocated");`

Comment: OT: regarding: `exit(0);`  in general, returned 0 indicates success.  Suggest:  `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` Note: exit() and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed by `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: regarding: `(getLength(searched)`  this will return garbage and is undefined behavior.  Suggest: `(getLength(userInput )`

Comment: @Barmar I thought that allocating memory twice would make my code more efficient, as I could use malloc to only use the necessary memory required and then free the unneeded space.

Comment: If you're only allocating 20 bytes, the difference is negligible. It would make a difference if you were allocating 1000 bytes and then shrinking it. But see my answer where I use a local array instead of `malloc()` for the temporary buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code blocks differs here:

```
char *name = (char*)malloc(getLength(userInput)* sizeof(char));
      ^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^

char *searched = (char*)malloc(getLength(searched)* sizeof(char));
      ^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

The second uses `searched` twice. So you different modify the original code correctly.

**However, notice that both code blocks are wrong.**

There are several problems with the code (both examples).

`scanf("%s",userInput);` is real bad as it let the user overflow your buffer. Look at `fgets` instead or at least do `scanf("%19s",userInput);`

Here:

```
char *name = (char*)malloc(getLength(userInput)* sizeof(char));
name = userInput;
```

the `malloc` line is useless as you overwrite `name` with `userInput` immediately after. So all `malloc` gives you is a memory leak.

And here

```
free(userInput);
```

you free the memory that `userInput` points to. However, since you did `name = userInput;` it **is also** the memory that `name` points to. So after the free, none of the pointers are valid.

My guess is that instead of:

```
name = userInput;
```

you would want

```
strcpy(name, userInput);
```

That said - I'm don't know what `getLength` is but maybe the `malloc` should be:

```
char *name = (char*)malloc(1 + getLength(userInput)* sizeof(char));
                           ^^^
```

to get memory for the string termination. At least that is what you do when using `strlen`

So:

```
  char *userInput = malloc(20);
  if(userInput == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }

  printf("\nEnter a name: \n");
  scanf("%19s",userInput);

  char *searched = malloc(1 + strlen(userInput ));
  if(searched == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }

  strcpy(searched, userInput);
  free(userInput);
```

But... what is the real purpose of the code?

It seems to be that `searched` shall hold (in dynamic allocated memory) a string entered by the user **and** that the amount dynamic allocated memory shall be exactly what is required to hold the string.

That could make sense in some application but not in your case!

The first `malloc` is for 20 chars. Consequently, the second `malloc` will be for 20 or less chars.

Since `malloc` has a memory overhead and some alignment requirement, the amount of real memory required by, e.g. `malloc(20)` is more than 20 bytes. In other words - the difference in **real memory** used by `malloc(20)` and `malloc(10)` is likely to be small. So the whole idea of the code is pretty useless - you don't save significant memory by doing the second `malloc` and the string copy.

So you should simply do:

```
  char *searched = malloc(20);
  if(searched == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }

  printf("\nEnter a name: \n");
  scanf("%19s",searched);

  // Go on using searched
  ...
  ...


  // Somewhere later in the code, call free
  free(searched);
```

The original code only makes sense if your program sometimes gets very long strings as input and sometimes very short. In that case the first `malloc` would be for a much bigger number, e.g. 1000000 chars, and then it would make sense to copy the input to a smaller buffer afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The code you found online, if you reproduced it correctly, is wrong. The problem is that you're freeing `userInput`, even though `searched` points to that memory.

You should copy the string from `userInput` to `searched` before freeing it.

But there's no need to use dynamic allocation for `userInput`. You can just use a local array.

You should use the length of `userInput` when allocating `searched`. And you need to add 1 to allow room for the null terminator.

You should check whether the allocation was successful before trying to copy `userInput` into it.

```
  char userInput[20];
  printf("\nEnter a name: ");
  scanf("%19s",userInput); // limit input length to 19 so it fits in userInput
  char *searched = malloc((strlen(userInput)+1)* sizeof(char));
  if(searched == NULL){
    printf("Memory not allocated");
    exit(0);
  }
  strcpy(searched, userInput);
```